# Pass regex flags to route in Phalcon micro app

Tags: php, regex, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm trying to define a route in a [Phalcon Micro App](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/micro.html#routes-with-parameters), but can't figure out how to pass the global flag to the regular expression. Here is my route

`/api/v1/product/detail/{sku:([\w\d]+-?)*[\w\d]*}`

Expecting both of these to match, however the later requires the global modifier to match.

- 8Z-WEXN-CG0H
- 025-3bags

How can I specify a flag in the regular expression? I did not see this specified in the documentation.

Comment: Doesn't it match both cases currently?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Did you check? https://regex101.com/r/0QQJeE/1

Comment: Yes, notice it requires the global flag - hence my question... I'm trying to solve it with a regex that doesn't need the global flag now.

Comment: In addition I'd say `\w` includes `\d` as part of match and you'd better go with `\w+(-\w+)*`

Comment: No, `g` is set because of multiple matches in separate lines. You only need one match at a time. Unset `g` and see the result.

Comment: When I unset `g` the second string not matched

Comment: Your route definition handles one URL at a time. So you don't need `g`.

Comment: However both are a match without global modifier if and only if you have one input value at a time.

Comment: OIC - I'd thought the test strings were treated individually in that tool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global modifier is set whenever you don't want to stop at first match and since you have one matching value at a time you don't need `g` modifier either.

Let's go with an example. Suppose your current input string is this:

```
/api/v1/product/detail/8Z-WEXN-CG0H
/api/v1/product/detail/025-3bags
```

Then your regex stops at first match since no `g`'s applied but if your input string is one of these at a time:

```
/api/v1/product/detail/8Z-WEXN-CG0H
```

```
/api/v1/product/detail/025-3bags
```

It works so you don't need `g` at all. And I'd suggest you to modify your regex into this simplified:

```
\w+(?:-\w+)*
```

As `\w` includes `\d` as part of a match.

Comment: Thank you sir - here is the final regex that got it working in phalcon `((\w+(?:-\w+)*)`. I had to use a non-capturing group on the inner group. Does that look legit to you? Seems to be working as I test in my app...

Comment: I don't see a reason for outer grouping but if that works, there you go.